# Passing form data to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a problem, im looking to pass very basic user input into a javascript function for javascript to then process that information, I am really only looking to pass strings, however I just want to learn the concept. Below is how I would (THINK) you'd do this, but it doesn't work and I am not sure why. Could someone show me how to do this simply and properly.

```
<body>

<form id="frm1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(fname, lname)" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(fname, lname) {
  console.log(fname);
  console.log(lname);
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: hi, perhaps `myFunction(this.form.fname.value, this.form.lname.value)`

Comment: @IronMan Where is ```this``` come from?

Comment: yeah. ` <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this.form.fname.value, this.form.lname.value)" value="Submit">` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach that might help:

You can see part of the following code in action at this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/m85yLoca/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="frm1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let fname = document.querySelector('#fname').value;
  let lname = document.querySelector('#lname').value;
  console.log(fname);
  console.log(lname);
}
</script>
</body>
```

I made sure to add `id=""` settings for the `fname` and `lname` form inputs. This can help us with individually specifying what input we want to access for later use.

This approach uses [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to pinpoint which form input you are wanting to access. I get the value of the input via the `.value` part at the end of the `document.querySelector()` lines and then assign these to individual variables `fname` and `lname`.

Then, you can access the individual `fname` and `lname` variables in your function.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by the following step.

1. getting the all input DOM value by `document.querySelectorAll()`. I didn't add `id` in each of the input. Instead, I select them all
2. select each one of them and assign the value to a variable.

```
<form id="frm1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" ><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" ><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   const inputValues = document.querySelectorAll('#frm1 input')
   const fname = inputValues[0].value;
   const lname = inputValues[1].value;

   console.log(fname, lname);
}
</script>
```

If later on, you need to submit the data to server. Just add the `onsumbit` attribute.

```
<form onsubmit="sendData()">
   //input and other structure

   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<script>
function sendData(){
   //pack all your input value
   //make the ajax call here    
}
</script>
```